# Cut straight lines with knife tool

Tags: workflow, snapping, knife-tool

How can I get the knife tool to snap to the same spot on another edge to get a straight cut. Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image]

When the line turns green the cut is straight. How can I do this in blender? I have tried using the magnet snapping tool but could not get it to work.

Comment: I think the closest you can get now is use *midpoint snap* (Ctrl) to snap both ends of the cut to the middle of the existing edges, then using edge slide (GG) to slide the edge over. Not very optimal, I agree..

Comment: As the cut is made relative to the camera i have found that using orthographic view is the quickest way to achieve the result but i agree that a sketchup style, allign cut to axis shortcut would be cool!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Press <kbd>A</kbd> while in knife mode to enable *Angle Constrain*.

Note that it snaps to angles relative to the view. For cuts on faces which are not aligned to any axis, you can:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to align the view to the face
2. Press <kbd>K</kbd> to enter knife mode, then <kbd>A</kbd> to enable *Angle Constrain*:

   [image]

More information on Angle Constrain can be found in the [Blender Reference Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html#controls)

Comment: additionall "Z". keys K, Z, C to cut though the entire (selected?) mesh, not just the face selected with the knife tool (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7156/3038)

Comment: Seems like they should have the option to constrain angles relative to the geometry, since I imagine people rarely want to define their angles relative to the view

Comment: Please note that you have to start cutting first, and THEN you press C. Else something strange happens.

Answer (score 15):

### Angle Constrain

You can use <kbd>C</kbd> while using the [Knife Tool](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide) to enable *Angle Constrain*. This will enable you to cut at the following angles (with reference to your current view):

- Vertically
- Horizontally
- At 45° angles

Also, notice that when you start to use the Knife tool, the 3D View Header bar changes to show you all the available Hotkeys to perform all possible actions with the Knife:

[image]

- <kbd>LMB</kbd>: *Define cut lines*
- <kbd>RETURN</kbd>/<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>: *Confirm*
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>/<kbd>RMB</kbd>: *Cancel*
- <kbd>E</kbd>: *New Cut*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>: Toggle *Midpoint Snap*
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>: Toggle *Ignore Snap*
- <kbd>C</kbd>: Toggle *Angle Constrain*
- <kbd>Z</kbd>: Toggle *Cut Through*

(**NOTE:** It is common in Blender to have available Hotkeys shown in the 3D View Header bar while using a tool, so check there while using other tools too.)

Comment: Is there a way to snap the cuts to grid?