# Is there a simple way to cut a face or add an edge to an existing face?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

Subdivide takes a single face and divides it into quads. I only want to add a single edge to the face off to the side.

Most of the answers I found on the internet recommend using the Knife tool but the knife tool does not cut a single face the way you would think. In fact I have no idea what logic the knife tool uses but it's not at all intuitive: (below gif).

I'm trying to add a single box to the bottom of this desk object to extrude into a drawer box, but I cannot get a face to work with on the bottom of the desk.

[image]

Comment: Try adding a Loop-Cut with *Ctrl+R*. Or select both vertices of the edges you want to halfen and hit *W* (specials menu) and select *Subdivide*. Then select only these two new vertices and hit *F* to create an edge between them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the knife tool is actually quite easy and intuitive.

Hit <kbd>K</kbd> to start, point your mouse to the starting point and left-click, then drag the line to the second point, left-click again (then to the third, fourth...). When you have set the end point of your cut, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done.

Hit <kbd>C</kbd> to use *Angle Constraint*

If that doesn't work (e.g. no cuts showing up) it's pretty sure that your model has double faces. Hit <kbd>W</kbd> - "Remove Doubles".

To remove doubles in Blender 2.8, you need to hit <kbd>M</kbd> and select *By Distance" to remove the doubles in that version.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8955/cut-straight-lines-with-knife-tool

Comment: @cegaton Yes, but if you notice, in my GIF I'm using the Knife tool exactly as described and it's creating a cut on a totally unrelated face.

Comment: The double issue was the problem it seems. There were two edges where the boxes intersected causing the kinfe tool to behave strangely.

Comment: @leigero, this is why "remove doubles" has become second nature to me. Another method (when remove doubles fails) is to switch from vertex or edge select to face select. When you see dots on edges you instantly know that something's gone wrong.

Comment: Angle constraint works like a charm!

Comment: you can also hold CTRL to magnetise the the cursor while cutting

Comment: It seems to follow the perspective of the camera and not the face you're trying to cut. I used C, which snaps straight down, but straight down on the camera view, not the Z axis. Very weird tool.

Answer (score 25):

Select the 2 edges and use the subdivide tool. you will have a new edge so you can then bevel it to have more of them and do whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: use right-click -> Subdivide

Answer (score 2):

If the table is a single mesh, you can use the Loop Cut and Slide tool to add new rings of mesh around the object. Click on the tool (left-side of the 3D viewer) and then place your mouse near the outside edge of the side of the table you want to divide. A pink line will show up inside the mesh at the middle point between the faces. Roll the mouse wheel to add or remove extra mesh lines. Click the LMB once when happy with the number of lines. Move the mouse to adjust their position to where you want them, and then click LMB again when happy.

Answer (score 1):

Step by Step Process. Select the face you want to effect, press CTRL + I to invert the selection, press H to hide the faces, Press CTRL + R to create a Loop Cut.
after you are done Creating your Loop cuts, press ALT + H to un-hide the faces.

now if any face is causing issues With CTRL + R.
Step by Step Process. Select the face that is causing an issue, Delete face,
Select Vertices, press CRTL + F pick Select Grid Fill.

A quick way of Selection Vertices ALT + Left Click.

hope it makes sense? xD

Comment: Firstly, you can do hiding much simpler. Select the face(s) you want to keep, press _Shift_ + _H_ to hide unselected faces. Secondly, as you said, the _Loop Cut_ tool might fail because you can _only_ use it on quads. With tris and n-gons this doesn't work. Suppose you have a simple n-gon with 5 vertices... how do you make the _Grid Fill_ tool work? Thirdly, if one of the vertices of the hole where you deleted the face connects to more edges and there is a different hole between those edges, then _Alt_ + _LMB_ will select the vertices of that hole, too - although you might not want to fill it.