# How can I remove part of a mesh without distorting a rigged character?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I am trying to remove the tail from [Rinky the red squirrel's](https://peach.blender.org) mesh. I used the [bisect tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5321/18748) to trim it off. But when I switch back to object mode, his face is bizarrely warped:

[image: Rinky]

How can I chop off his tail, while leaving his rest pose intact? (I need the rest pose to remain the same because the next step is exporting to FBX, which seems to only recognise the rest pose.)

Rinky is from *Big Buck Bunny* (c) copyright 2008, Blender Foundation / [www.bigbuckbunny.org](http://www.bigbuckbunny.org)

Shared under [CC-BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)

Comment: Well this is definitely a side effect of whatever rigging setup was used to create him. I would *guess* that for whatever reason, the tail was important enough to the animation (for balance perhaps) that other bones in the rig were made to be dependent on the tail. I would first try removing his armature as a test to see if that fixes it, and then undo that, go back, and try to study his rig in detail. Worst case scenario, you re-rig him from scratch.