# How to split a Box or a Mesh with a Plane and keep both sides?

Tags: modeling

I understand there are a couple of options we can do in Blender in term of slicing a mesh (in my case I want to slice a box) :

- Bisect Tool
- Knife Tool (this one is too artistic for my purpose, hard to be precise)
- Boolean > Difference
  But none of them provide a "Keep both" sides of the slices.

I know I can duplicate an the object first. Then slice both objects while keeping the opposite section.
This is quite tedious as I need to perform this so many time.

Is there a way to just simply keep both?

I'm on **Blender 2.9**.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Cutting a mesh in half](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/cutting-a-mesh-in-half)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the Bool Tool add on.  Bool Tool is included with Blender.  It needs enabling.

Step 1 Enable Bool Tool: [image: Bool Tool add on]

Step 2:  I have a Cube that i have intersected with a plane.
[image: Cube with a Plane intersecting it.]

Step 3: Select the Plane **first**, hold down Shift key then Select the Cube
[image]

Step 4:  From the Properties Panel (Press N if its not visible)  go to Edit then Bool Tool
[image]

Step 5:  Use the Slice option in Either the Auto Boolean or Brush Boolean menus.
Result is a Cube cut into two sections with faces applied between the two.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a loop cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) around the cube where you want to separate it. Select all the faces on one "half" of the cube then press <kbd>P</kbd> (Separate), and pick "By selection". The cube will now be 2 pieces (two separate objects).

[image: Select]

Comment: To add to Christopher's answer, if you want to keep the two parts as one object, once you've selected the faces press 'P' (Split) and you'll find that the selected part can be moved independently with the 'g' key.

Comment: Sorry. That should be press 'Y' not 'P'!

Comment: Thanks @christopher-bennett but after that I ended up with two hollow cubes. Each cubes missing a face. I can always add the missing face, but that seems a bit lengthy process. I the analogy I'm looking for  is: I have a lumber, I want to cut it with a circular saw. I will ended up with two closed boxes. What is the easiest way to achieve this in Blender?